# Concatenate excel sheets using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

[image]My first time using pandas. I am sure the answer is something along the lines of storing the worksheet names in a list, then looping through the list based on the name I am looking for. I'm just not experienced enough to know how to do that.

The goal is to use pandas to extract and concatenate data from multiple worksheets from a user selected workbook. The final output being a single worksheet excel containing all data extracted from the various worksheets.

The excel workbook consist of approximately 100 worksheets. The qty of visible sheets will always vary, with the qty of sheets occurring before 'Main Frames BUP1' being variable as well.

I currently have the portion of code checking for page visibility working. I can not seem to figure out how to start at a specific worksheet when that worksheets position in the workbook could vary (i.e. not always the 3rd worksheet starting from 0 it could be the 5th in a users excel). It will however, always be the sheet that data should start being pulled from. Everything I find are examples of specifying specific sheets to read.

Any help/direction would be appreciated.

```
# user selected file from GUI
xl = values["-xl_file-"]
loc = os.path.dirname(xl)

xls = pd.ExcelFile(xl)
sheets = xls.book.worksheets

for x in sheets:
    print(x.title, x.sheet_state)
    if x.sheet_state == 'visible':
        df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=None, header=None,
             skiprows=5, nrows=32, usecols='M:AD'), ignore_index=True)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'{loc}/test.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, 'bananas')
writer.save()
```

*******Additional clarification on final goal: Exclude all sheets occurring before 'Main Frames BUP 1', only consider visible sheets, pull data from 'M6:AD37', if entire row is blank do not add(or at least remove) from data frame, stop pulling data at the sheet just before a worksheet who's name has a partial match to 'panel'

If I create a dictionary of visible sheets, how do you create a new dictionary useing that dictionary only consisting of 'Main Frames BUP 1' to whatever sheet occurs just before a partial match of 'panel'? Then I can use that dictionary for my data pull.

Comment: Do you want the sheets to be concatenated to like-named sheets in the output workbook, or combine all sheets into one big sheet?

Comment: @crunker99 One big sheet. Sorry missed specifying that in my question. Turning data from a specified area of each worksheet in a multi-worksheet workbook, into a single worksheet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a minimal sample myself and worked it out for you.

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('data/Test.xlsx')
sheets = xls.book.worksheets
sList = [x.title for x in sheets if x.sheet_state == 'visible']
        
dfs = [pd.read_excel('data/Test.xlsx', sheet_name=s, skiprows=5, nrows=32, usecols='M:AD') for s in sList]
dfconcat = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Now you need adjust the columns, headers and so on as you did in your question. I hope that it works out for you. From my side here it worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help. I kept trying to do everything in the data frame instead of organizing my list first. I got too focused on making one aspect work, to realize I was coming at the problem incorrectly.

Comment: @Rand0mdude I am glad that I could help. That is the aim of this community. I have been there, too focused on a certain aspect and missing the whole picture.
All the best dude.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard without actually see what is going on with your data.
I believe that what you are missing is that you need to create one dataframe first and after concat the others. Also you need to pass a sheet(x) in order to pandas be able to read it, otherwise it will become a dictionary. In case it does not work, get the first sheet and create a df, then you concat.

```
# user selected file from GUI
xl = values["-xl_file-"]
loc = os.path.dirname(xl)


xls = pd.ExcelFile(xl)
sheets = xls.book.worksheets


df = pd.DataFrame()
for x in sheets:
    print(x.title, x.sheet_state)
    if x.sheet_state == 'visible':
        df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=x, header=None,
             skiprows=5, nrows=32, usecols='M:AD'), ignore_index=True)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'{loc}/test.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, 'bananas')
writer.save()
```

You can also put all the dfs in a dictionary, again it is difficult without knowing what you are working with.

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('yourFile.xlsx')

#collect all sheet names
sheets = xl.sheet_names

#build dictionaries from all sheets passing None to sheet_name
diDF = pd.read_excel('yourFile.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

di = {k : diDF[k] for k in diDF if k in sheets}


for x in sheets:
    if x.sheet_state == 'visible':
        dfs = {x: pd.DataFrame(di[x])}
```

Comment: Exception has occurred: TypeError
'>=' not supported between instances of 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' and 'int   on the pd.concat line.

Comment: @Rand0mdude I am in the limbo here dude.  It is necessary to have a minimal sample to understand what it is going on.  Try to put all the sheets that you need in a dictionary, then from there you can concat.

xl = pd.ExcelFile('yourFile.xlsx')

#collect all sheet names
sheets = xl.sheet_names

#passing all dfs to a dict format
dfs = {d: pd.DataFrame(dict[s]) for d, s in zip(sheets, sheets)}

for x in sheets:
    if x.sheet_state == 'visible':
        dfs = {x: pd.DataFrame(dict[x])}

Comment: I will try the things you suggest. The excel sheet has a lot of vba in it or else I would have provided it in the question. No body would trust a file like that, especially from some random dude. :)

Comment: @Rand0mdude I dont want the data dude, I mean when you ask a question as such it is good to provide a minimal sample, like you create a minimal sample in excel and make it available. I work for companies and I understand that you can share these things. So next time you are asking for help, make it easier to be helped.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to imply I was not willing to share it, just that I didn't know a good way to do it. I made a simple excel as an example but since the site doesn't allow file attachments, I took a snippet to help clarify. If that helps at all.

Comment: @Rand0mdude no offense taken. I will have at it tomorrow, in my timezone is time for bed. Take care.

Comment: I think a dictionary that can narrow to only visible pages, then narrow to only pages from the start to stop mentioned. Then use that dictionary for the data frame is the way to go. I just don't know how to structure that.